# Ajax отправляет по 2 запроса POST и GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование, django

Есть следующий HTML+Django шаблон

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="radio_select">
        <button class="toggleSel circlesSel" type='button'>
            <span class="flaticon-meeting"></span>
            <span>Добавить</span>
        </button>
        <div class="radio_list">
            {% for rt in relation_types %}
                <div class="com" {% for rs in relationships %}
                  {% if rt.title.lower == rs.type_of_relation %}style="color: grey; cursor: default" readonly='readonly' onclick='window.event.returnValue=false'{% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}>
                  <div class="checkboxwrap">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="{{ rt.id }}">
                      <label for="{{ rt.id }}" {% for rs in relationships %}
                        {% if rt.title.lower == rs.type_of_relation %}style="cursor: default"{% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}>{{ rt.title }}</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

На странице он отрисовывается в следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть в том, что это своеобразный выпадающий список с чекбоксами. По нажатию на кнопку `button` - он раскрывается и появляются поля мультиселекта.
После выбора опять же таки по нажатию на эту кнопку список обратно сворачивается и происходит `ajax` запрос.

Вот сам скрипт.

```
<script>
  $('.checkbox').change(function(){
      let objCheck = $('.checkbox');
      let listCheck = [];

      $.each(objCheck, (i,e) =>{
          if ($(e).prop('checked')) {
              listCheck.push($(e).attr('id'));
          }
      })
      console.log(listCheck);
      run_ajax = $('.toggleSel').attr('data-click-state');
      if (run_ajax == '1') {
        $(".toggleSel").on('click', function() {

          data = {
                 'choices': listCheck
                 }
          console.log(data);

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "",
              data: data,
              error: function(result) {
                  alert('Произошла ошибка. Попробуйте позже.');
              }
          });
      });
    }
  })
</script>
```

Возможно, он не очень красиво составлен, но я в js начинающий...

Проблема заключается в том, что происходит два запроса `POST` и два запроса `GET`, причём один из запросов `POST` неполный.

Я пробовал переписать вызов `ajax'a` вот так

```
$(".toggleSel").off().on('click', function() {
```

Отправляется один запрос, но список не сворачивается.

В общем, помогите сделать так, чтобы отправлялся 1 запрос `POST` и список сворачивался. Это всё должно происходить без перезагрузки страницы (сейчас так и происходит).

За сворачивание/развораивание списка отвечает атрибут `data-click-state` в `button`. Он есть только в развёрнутом состоянии и значение его равно `1`. Также в развёрнутом состоянии появляется класс `active`

**upd. script**

```
<script>
  var listCheck = [];
  $('.checkbox').change(function(){
      let objCheck = $('.checkbox');
      listCheck = [];

      $.each(objCheck, (i,e) =>{
          if ($(e).prop('checked')) {
              listCheck.push($(e).attr('id'));
          }
      })
  })
  $(".toggleSel").on('click', function() {
      run_ajax = $('.toggleSel').attr('data-click-state');
      if (run_ajax == '1') {
        data = {
               'choices': listCheck
               }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: data,
            error: function(result) {
                alert('Произошла ошибка. Попробуйте позже.');
            }
        });
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
          if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
          }
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дальше запросов будет не два, а больше, потому что на каждое изменение `$('.checkbox')` Вы навешиваете новый обработчик `$(".toggleSel").on('click'`. Вынесите второе из первого.

---

```
var listCheck = [];

$('.checkbox').change(function(){
  let objCheck = $('.checkbox');
  listCheck = [];
  ...
});
```

и

```
$(".toggleSel").on('click', function() {
  ...
});
```

должны быть на одном уровне, а не один внутри другого.

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы подразумеваете под "Вынесите второе из первого"...(

Comment: Да, я понял, в чём проблема. Но пока что не понимаю, как решить её. Написать два разных скрипта?

Comment: Видимо, я делаю что-то не так. Обновил код в посте. Возможно, это потому что `.attr('data-click-state');` есть только у раскрытого списка? Также вряд ли будет виден список `listCheck` во второй части скрипта

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Добавил в ответ.

Comment: отлично. Спасибо. У меня ещё один вопрос. Возможно, это уже не по теме, но всё же. Не знаете, как сбросить все выбранные селекты после отправки запроса (без перезагрузки страницы, при сворачивании списка)?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 что значит "сбрасывать"?

Comment: Чтобы "галочки" у выбранных селектов исчезли. Уже разобрался, как это сделать. Обновил код, если интересно. Можете, какие-то курсы, туториалы по js посоветовать?